# jQuery file conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a test website for a future project and I am having jQuery issues. It is a static HTML5 website with a social widget, when I remove one of the jQuery lines, the site loses its styling and the widget looks pretty. When I add that jQuery I removed, the site will look good, but the widget will look really bad. How can I fix this conflict issue? I will add the code to the main website on here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html><head>
    <title>test site</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->

    <!-- Social Widget Goodies Start -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dcsmt.css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/js/jquery.plugins.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/js/jquery.site.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.social.media.tabs.1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#social-tabs').dcSocialTabs({
            widgets: 'twitter,facebook',
            twitterId: '20782546',
            facebookId: '69431101263',
            fblikeId: '69431101263',
            fbrecId: 'https://www.facebook.com/ArkansasState',
            tweetId: '20782546',
            autoClose: true,
            facebook: {
            text: 'content'
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
    <!-- Social Widget Goodies End... -->
</head>
<body class="homepage">
    <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div id="header" class="container">

                <!-- Logo -->
                    <h1 id="logo"><a href="#"><img style="margin-top:10px;" src="images/logo_tiny.png" width="147" height="50" alt="logo"></a></h1>

                <!-- Nav -->
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Main Menu</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Magna phasellus</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Etiam dolore nisl</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Phasellus consequat</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Phasellus consequat</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Magna phasellus</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Etiam dolore nisl</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Veroeros feugiat</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link#01</a></li>
                            <li class="break"><a href="#">Link#02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link#03</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

            </div>

            <!-- Hero -->
                <section id="hero" class="container">
                    <header>
                        <h2>ASTATE EMERGENCY PORTAL
                        <br/>
                        our main website is currently down</h2>
                    </header>
                    <p>Please scroll down and use the links provided in this portal
                    to access external applications like<br> e-mail, blackboard, etc. etc.</p>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="http://www.astate.edu" class="button">www.astate.edu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>

        </div>

    <!-- Features 1 -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="6u feature">
                        <div class="image-wrapper first">
                            <a href="#" class="image featured first"><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <header>
                            <h2>For Students<br />
                            Access your E-mail Account Here</h2>
                        </header>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur et sed adipiscing elit. Curabitur vel 
                        sem sit dolor neque semper magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur et sed 
                        adipiscing elit. Curabitur vel sem sit.</p>
                        <ul class="actions">
                            <li><a href="#" class="button">Enter</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                    <section class="6u feature">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <header>
                            <h2>For Faculty & Staff<br />
                            Access your E-mail Account here</h2>
                        </header>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur et sed adipiscing elit. Curabitur vel 
                        sem sit dolor neque semper magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur et sed 
                        adipiscing elit. Curabitur vel sem sit.</p>
                        <ul class="actions">
                            <li><a href="#" class="button">Enter</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Promo -->
        <div id="promo-wrapper">
            <section id="promo">
                <h2>Live social updates</h2>
                <a href="#" class="button">Do not press</a>
            </section>
        </div>

    <!-- Features 2 -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <section class="container">
                <header class="major">
                    <h2>Sed magna consequat lorem curabitur tempus</h2>
                    <p>Elit aliquam vulputate egestas euismod nunc semper vehicula lorem blandit</p>
                </header>
                <div class="row features">
                    <section class="4u feature">
                        <div class="image-wrapper first">
                            <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/pic03.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur et sed adipiscing elit. Curabitur 
                        vel sem sit dolor neque semper magna lorem ipsum.</p>
                    </section>
                    <section class="4u feature">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur et sed adipiscing elit. Curabitur 
                        vel sem sit dolor neque semper magna lorem ipsum.</p>
                    </section>
                    <section class="4u feature">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur et sed adipiscing elit. Curabitur 
                        vel sem sit dolor neque semper magna lorem ipsum.</p>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <ul class="actions major">
                    <li><a href="#" class="button">Elevate my awareness</a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer-wrapper">
            <div id="footer" class="container">
                <header class="major">
                    <h2>Keep in touch with us</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur et sed adipiscing elit. Curabitur vel sem sit<br />
                    dolor neque semper magna lorem ipsum feugiat veroeros lorem ipsum dolore.</p>
                </header>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="6u">
                        <form method="post" action="#">
                            <div class="row collapse-at-2 half">
                                <div class="6u">
                                    <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="6u">
                                    <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row half">
                                <div class="12u">
                                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row half">
                                <div class="12u">
                                    <ul class="actions">
                                        <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
                                        <li><input type="reset" value="Clear form" /></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </section>
                    <section class="6u">
                        <div class="row collapse-at-2 flush">
                            <ul class="divided icons 6u">
                                <li class="icon fa-twitter"><a href="#"><span class="extra">twitter.com/</span>untitled</a></li>
                                <li class="icon fa-facebook"><a href="#"><span class="extra">facebook.com/</span>untitled</a></li>
                                <li class="icon fa-dribbble"><a href="#"><span class="extra">dribbble.com/</span>untitled</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="divided icons 6u">
                                <li class="icon fa-instagram"><a href="#"><span class="extra">instagram.com/</span>untitled</a></li>
                                <li class="icon fa-youtube"><a href="#"><span class="extra">youtube.com/</span>untitled</a></li>
                                <li class="icon fa-pinterest"><a href="#"><span class="extra">pinterest.com/</span>untitled</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="copyright" class="container">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li>&copy;2014 - ASTATE Emergency Portal. All rights reserved.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
<div id="social-tabs"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: *"when I remove one of the sites jQuerys"* What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry that was a weird auto-correct.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the ordering of your scripts. Rather than just removing `js/jquery.min.js`, you should move your other jQuery script to this position:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  
         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
...
```

...otherwise the JavaScript files located above this jQuery include's current position may not wait for jQuery to load before attempting to execute then not-yet-present jQuery calls.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer, I removed it and added the jQuery to the top as you said but still I have the same issue